# I have a bunch of event times. How do I pick out and group together the closest ones?

Tags: statistics

Here's an example:

Let's say I have the following events, Event A at 5:05, Event B at 4:55, Event C at 4:49, Event D at 6:03, Event E at 9:05.

Now, when I do whatever statistics function required, I should get 3, and only three values: Approx. 5:00, 6:03, and 9:05.

So I am just wondering how I use all this data, and what functions I can perform to get the groupings and put them into a set.

Please let me know if you don't understand my questions.

Comment: Do you mean "Approx. *5:05*, 6:03 and 9:05"?

Comment: @MRicci Well it doesn't really matter, my point was that the function should've noticed that 5:05, 4:55, 4:49 were close together, so it groups them together as one, and can average their times out to get the "grouping time"

Comment: @MRicci and as a further clarification, this should be a mathematical function. I can represent the times as integer numbers (Unix epoch timestamp), so they can be averaged, and go through mathematical functions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, you are looking for a *[clustering](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cluster_analysis)* algorithm. The field of cluster analysis involves grouping together data points which are in some sense "close". There are many different ways of doing this, which you can read about in the link.

If you pass your data set through a clustering algorithm, you could tag each point which some label designating which cluster it belongs to.

Comment: Do you have any recommendations for this? I will definitely read through the page, but it seems oriented towards people with a strong statistics background.

All I have, as mentioned, is a key, value pair, with the key being an event, and the value being an integer representation of the time.

Should I focus on any specific part of that page? Whatever clustering function I use will have to be implemented in one of my JAVA programs.

Comment: Each algorithm has its strengths and weaknesses. If you care about identifying clusters and eliminating outliers, try a density-based algorithm like DBSCAN. If you're willing to stipulate the number of clusters beforehand, try k-means. If you think your data follows some mixture model (it is drawn from a collection of probability distributions), try something like expectation maximization.

Comment: Alright thanks, and would you know of any existing libraries for this that are in JAVA?

Comment: I'm not sure. I know that there is plenty of stuff for MATLAB.